# What the risks of rooting your Android?

Tags: android, root

Besides your warranty getting voided, what potential security risks are there with rooting your Android?

Comment: Probably the most damaging risk is potentially bricking your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you do once it's rooted. Some phones such as HTC make it easy for developers to root them. Risks depend on your carefulness. Don't delete system files.

Security - more security benefits than risks if you know what you're doing.

Comment: This is not true. A rooted device sacrifices many security protections. The risk is not simply that you might do something wrong and break things. In fact, there are exploits that only work on rooted devices for this very reason.

Comment: Depends if you know what you are doing. With a rooted device, you can eliminate a lot of secret information being transmitted without your consent. Sure there my be exploits, but if you know your stuff benefits outweigh risks by far -- especially if you're concerned about privacy.

Comment: Hopefully, only someone with the appropriate knowledge would root their phone to begin with.